# Parallel *ply within functions

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr

I want to use the parallel functionality of the `plyr` package within functions.

I would have thought that the proper way to export objects that have been created within the body of the function (in this example, the object is `df_2`) is as follows

```
# rm(list=ls())
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)

workers=makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,core=2)

plyr_test=function() {
  df_1=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
  df_2=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=3:4)

  #export df_2 via .paropts  
  ddply(df_1,"type",.parallel=TRUE,.paropts=list(.export="df_2"),.fun=function(y) {
    merge(y,df_2,all=FALSE,by="type")
  })
}
plyr_test()
stopCluster(workers)
```

However, this throws an error

```
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  unable to find variable "df_2"
```

So I did some research and found out that it works if I export `df_2` manually

```
workers=makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,core=2)

plyr_test_2=function() {
  df_1=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
  df_2=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=3:4)

  #manually export df_2
  clusterExport(cl=workers,varlist=list("df_2"),envir=environment())

  ddply(df_1,"type",.parallel=TRUE,.fun=function(y) {
    merge(y,df_2,all=FALSE,by="type")
  })
}
plyr_test_2()
stopCluster(workers)
```

It gives the correct result

```
  type x.x x.y
1    a   1   3
2    b   2   4
```

But I have also found out that the following code works

```
workers=makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,core=2)

plyr_test_3=function() {
  df_1=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
  df_2=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=3:4)

  #no export at all!
  ddply(df_1,"type",.parallel=TRUE,.fun=function(y) {
    merge(y,df_2,all=FALSE,by="type")
  })
}
plyr_test_3()
stopCluster(workers)
```

`plyr_test_3()` also gives the correct result and I don't understand why. I would have thought that I have to export `df_2`...

My question is: What is the right way to deal with parallel `*ply` within functions? Obviously, `plyr_test()` is incorrect. I somehow have the feeling that the manual export in `plyr_test_2()` is useless. But I also think that `plyr_test_3()` is kind of bad coding style. Could someone please elaborate on that? Thanks guys!

Comment: Just as a side note: since you're using `ddply`, you could also try using **dplyr** which is the next version of **plyr** for data frames and it might speed up your code performance more than parallelization of `ddply`. See the [Introduction to dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: And another note for future questions: don't put `rm(list=ls())` uncommented in your question. Others might run the code without noticing it and thereby remove important data from their sessions.

Comment: :) You are right. Sorry about that.

Comment: The code that I gave above is a just minimal example. Actually, I do not even use a `merge` in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `plyr_test` is that `df_2` is defined in `plyr_test` which isn't accessible from the `doParallel` package, and therefore it fails when it tries to export `df_2`. So that is a scoping issue. `plyr_test2` avoids this problem because is doesn't try to use the `.export` option, but as you guessed, the call to `clusterExport` is not needed.

The reason that both `plyr_test2` and `plyr_test3` succeed is that `df_2` is serialized along with the anonymous function that is passed to the `ddply` function via the `.fun` argument. In fact, both `df_1` and `df_2` are serialized along with the anonymous function because that function is defined inside `plyr_test2` and `plyr_test3`. It's helpful that `df_2` is included in this case, but the inclusion of `df_1` is unnecessary and may hurt your performance.

As long as `df_2` is captured in the environment of the anonymous function, no other value of `df_2` will ever be used, regardless of what you export. Unless you can prevent it from being captured, it is pointless to export it either with `.export` or `clusterExport` because the captured value will be used. You can only get yourself into trouble (as you did the `.export`) by trying to export it to the workers.

Note that in this case, foreach does not auto-export `df_2` because it isn't able to analyze the body of the anonymous function to see what symbols are referenced. If you call foreach directly without using an anonymous function, then it will see the reference and auto-export it, making it unnecessary to explicitly export it using `.export`.

You could prevent the environment of `plyr_test` from being serialized along with the anonymous function by modifying it's environment before passing it to `ddply`:

```
plyr_test=function() {
  df_1=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
  df_2=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=3:4)
  clusterExport(cl=workers,varlist=list("df_2"),envir=environment())
  fun=function(y) merge(y, df_2, all=FALSE, by="type")
  environment(fun)=globalenv()
  ddply(df_1,"type",.parallel=TRUE,.fun=fun)
}
```

One of the advantages of the `foreach` package is that it doesn't encourage you to create a function inside of another function that might be capturing a bunch of variables accidentally.

---

This issue suggests to me that `foreach` should include an option called `.exportenv` that is similar to the `clusterExport` `envir` option. That would be very helpful for `plyr`, since it would allow `df_2` to be correctly exported using `.export`. However, that exported value still wouldn't be used unless the environment containing `df_2` was removed from the `.fun` function.

Comment: How do you explain that ARobertson's example with the dummy variable `df_2='hi'; plyr_test("df_2",T);` works? Obviously, the nonsense definition `df_2='hi'` before `plyr_test("df_2",T)` makes the export of `df_2` work. What I do not understand is why the correct version of `df_2` (defined within `plyr_test`) gets exported rather than `df_2='hi'`.

Comment: I think I understand. `df_2` in `plyr_test` is exported no matter whether there is a dummy `df_2='hi'` before `plyr_test` or not. But using `.export="df_2"` would trigger `ddply` to search for `df_2` in its search path. Since `ddply` is a function that was defined outside of `plyr_test`, it can only find `df_2` if it's in `.GlobalEnv`. If there is no dummy `df_2='hi'` in `.GlobalEnv` it will throw an error. If it finds `df_2='hi'`, it will try to export it too. In the latter case, I guess it would throw a warning similar to the one in my `foreach` example. But that warning is probably omitted.

Comment: @cryo111 Close. `df_2` in `plyr_test` is *captured* regardless of anything else. Using `.export="df_2"` will fail unless it's defined in `.GlobalEnv` (although this exported value will not be used). But foreach won't issue any warning if you use `.export="df_2"` because it doesn't auto-export `.df_2` when called from `ddply` because it isn't able to analyze the body of the anonymous function. I added more explanation in my answer to address your comments, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a scope issue.

Here is my "test suite" that allows me to .export different variables or avoid creating df_2 inside the function. I add and remove a dummy df_2 and df_3 outside of the function and compare.

```
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)

workers=makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,core=2)

plyr_test=function(exportvar,makedf_2) {
  df_1=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
  if(makedf_2){
    df_2=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=3:4)
  }
  print(ls())

  ddply(df_1,"type",.parallel=TRUE,.paropts=list(.export=exportvar,.verbose = TRUE),.fun=function(y) {
    z <- merge(y,df_2,all=FALSE,by="type")
  })
}
ls()
rm(df_2,df_3)
plyr_test("df_2",T)
plyr_test("df_2",F)
plyr_test("df_3",T)
plyr_test("df_3",F)
plyr_test(NULL,T) #ok
plyr_test(NULL,F)
df_2='hi'
ls()
plyr_test("df_2",T) #ok
plyr_test("df_2",F)
plyr_test("df_3",T)
plyr_test("df_3",F)
plyr_test(NULL,T) #ok
plyr_test(NULL,F)
df_3 = 'hi'
ls()
plyr_test("df_2",T) #ok
plyr_test("df_2",F)
plyr_test("df_3",T) #ok
plyr_test("df_3",F)
plyr_test(NULL,T) #ok
plyr_test(NULL,F)
rm(df_2)
ls()
plyr_test("df_2",T)
plyr_test("df_2",F)
plyr_test("df_3",T) #ok
plyr_test("df_3",F)
plyr_test(NULL,T) #ok
plyr_test(NULL,F)
```

I don't know why, but .export looks for df_2 in the global environment outside of the function, (I saw parent.env() in the code, which might be "more correct" than global environment) while the calculation requires the variable to be in the same environment as ddply and automatically exports it.

Using a dummy variable for df_2 outside of the function allows .export to work, while the calculation uses the df_2 inside.

When .export can't find the variable outside of the function, it outputs:

```
Error in e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) : 
  unable to find variable "df_2"
```

With a df_2 dummy variable outside of the function but without one inside, .export is fine but ddply outputs:

```
Error in do.ply(i) : task 1 failed - "object 'df_2' not found"
```

It's possible that since this is a small example or maybe not parallelizable, it's actually running on one core and avoiding the need to export anything. A bigger example might fail without the .export, but someone else can try that.

Comment: Interesting test suite! Especially the `df_2` dummy variable example. Please look at my "comment" (posted as an answer) below.

Comment: Perhaps one of those cases where the problem would be solved if they had used parent.frame instead. This works correctly inside functions too. I have had headaches over this kind of scoping problem before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395712/copying-dimnames-without-copying-objects

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ARobertson for your help!
It's very interesting that `plyr_test("df_2",T)` works when a dummy object `df_2` was defined outside of the function body.

As it seems `ddply` ultimately calls `llply` which, in turn, calls `foreach(...) %dopar% {...}`.

I have also tried to reproduce the problem with `foreach`, but `foreach` works fine.

```
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)

workers=makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,core=2)

foreach_test=function() {
  df_1=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
  df_2=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=3:4)
  foreach(y=split(df_1,df_1$type),.combine="rbind",.export="df_2") %dopar% {
    #also print process ID to be sure that we really use different R script processes
    cbind(merge(y,df_2,all=FALSE,by="type"),Sys.getpid())
  }
}

foreach_test()
stopCluster(workers)
```

It throws the warning

```
Warning message:
In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
  already exporting variable(s): df_2
```

but it returns the correct result

```
  type x.x x.y Sys.getpid()
1    a   1   3          216
2    b   2   4         1336
```

So, `foreach` seems to automatically export `df_2`. Indeed, the `foreach` [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf) states that

> ... %dopar% function noticed that those variables were referenced, and
>   that they were defined in the current environment. In that case
>   %dopar% will automatically export them to the parallel execution
>   workers once, and use them for all of the expression evaluations for
>   that foreach execution ....

Therefore we can omit `.export="df_2"` and use

```
library(plyr)
library(doParallel)

workers=makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(workers,core=2)

foreach_test_2=function() {
  df_1=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=1:2)
  df_2=data.frame(type=c("a","b"),x=3:4)
  foreach(y=split(df_1,df_1$type),.combine="rbind") %dopar% {
    #also print process ID to be sure that we really use different R script processes
    cbind(merge(y,df_2,all=FALSE,by="type"),Sys.getpid())
  }
}

foreach_test_2()
stopCluster(workers)
```

instead. This evaluates without a warning.

ARobertson's dummy variable example and the fact that `foreach` works fine make me now think that there is a problem in how *ply handles environments.

My conclusion is:

Both functions `plyr_test_3()` and `foreach_test_2()` (that do not explicitly export `df_2`) run without errors and give the same result. Therefore, `ddply` with `parallel=TRUE` basically works. BUT using a more "verbose" coding style (i.e., explicitly exporting `df_2`) such as in `plyr_test()` throws an error whereas `foreach(...) %dopar% {...}` only throws a warning.