# C symbol name not in load table when exporting a function in foreach loop

Tags: c, r, parallel-foreach

This issue I posted here is actually due to the configuration of the servers. The package actually has no issue related to R/C.

I am developing an R package using foreach to speedup the computation. To illustrate the structure of the package, I give a simplified R script and a C file below:

f3.R:

```r
f3 = function(.lst){
  cl <- makeCluster(2)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  
  f1 <-function(x){
    tmp <- .C("foo")
    x
  }
  
  f2 <-function(x){
    f1(x)
  }
  
  foreach(x=.lst, .verbose = TRUE ) %dopar% {
  f2(x)
  
  }
}
```

foo.c

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <R.h> 

extern "C" {
  void foo() {
    ;
  }
}
```

This package works very well on Mac OS, but throw an error message

> automatically exporting the following variables from the local environment:   f1, f2
>
> numValues: 1, numResults: 0, stopped: TRUE
>
> got results for task 1
>
> accumulate got an error result
>
> numValues: 1, numResults: 1, stopped: TRUE
>
> not calling combine function due to errors
>
> returning status TRUE
>
> Error in { : task 1 failed - "C symbol name "foo" not in load table"

This is what I’ve tried:

- add `.export = c("foo")`: doesn't help
- move `f1()` and `f2()` to a separate R script and add `.export = c("f1", "f2")`: work on Mac OS, too, but doesn't help on linux
- if I don't build a package, but load the functions above to the memory directly, then it works on both Mac OS and Linux
- if no C function is called (note that in my example, the C code did nothing), then it works on both Mac OS and Linux. However, if I move `f1()` and `f2()` to separate R scripts and add `.export = c("f1", "f2")`, it fails on Linux again.

Most of the posts found from the internet suggested using `.export` to export R functions, but I didn't find anything about exporting C symbols.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `Rcpp`?  It makes all this exporting of C functions much simpler.

Comment: I am maintaining an old package in which the c codes were developed several years ago by other people. We have plan to parallelize it. It is not easy to convert all of them to Rcpp. I will try Rcpp in my own new packages anyway (thanks for suggestion). Any suggestion for the current issue?

Comment: @cdeterman Even if I don't call c code in the package, when I move `f1()` and `f2()` to separate scripts and use `.export = c("f1", "f2")` in `foreach`, the package fails on Linux, too, giving error message: Error in { : task 1 failed - "could not find function "f1""

Comment: If possible, try to define the functions `f1` and `f2` outside of the body of `f3`. Also do _not_ to use `.export = c("f1", "f2")` in the `foreach` loop. Tell me whether this works. I had a similar problem recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492898/parallel-ply-within-functions

Comment: @cryo111 Under Mac OS: It works well if `f1` and `f2` are defined in the same or different script that contains `f3`, no matter the line `tmp <- .C("foo")` is called or not. Under Linux: I tried different combinations: (1) `f1` and `f2` are defined in the same or separate script of `f3`; (2) the line `tmp <- .C("foo") is commented or not. I always got error message: "could not find function "f2""

Comment: @HanZhang, do you by chance have this package on github?  I just created a package containing these functions on a Ubuntu system and it runs without problem.  It would be easiest to see what your package structure is that it may be causing things to be lost.  My working Linux package is on my github [here](https://github.com/cdeterman/cTest)

Comment: @cdeterman Thanks for uploading the package. I have posted my package on [github](https://github.com/zhangh12/ARTP2). But before doing so, I download yours and test it on two Linux servers and it fails as well. Both servers give same error message: Error in { : task 1 failed - "C symbol name "foo" not in load table". May be I need to contact the admin to figure out whether the server's configuration cause this issue or not.

Comment: @HanZhang, what are the specific architectures of these servers (i.e. CentOS, Ubuntu, etc. and version number such as 6.5 or 14.04).  I can spin up some virtual machines to try and test further.

Comment: @cdeterman it is CentOS release 5 (Final) and uname -a gives `Linux p2561 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 21 10:41:14 EST 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: @cdeterman One of my friend tested my package on his Linux Centos 6.6 and the package went well. I need to contact with the admin to find a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a package with all functions with a .C in it.
Then you add .packages = "yourpackage"  and export all functions needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here is a guide on [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).